# self index becomes argument

Tags: object, lua

Given is this object:

```
foo = { }

function foo:new( p1, p2 )
  local object = {}
  setmetatable( object, self )
  self.__index = self
  object .p1 = p1
  object .p2 = p2
  return object
end

function foo:bar( boolbar )
  self.p1 = not boolbar
  print( self.p1 )
end
```

Now I got another object, which is calling foos function by using a reference to foo ( foo is not accessable directly ) and passing an argument to it. Somehow, self becomes the argument.

```
reference_to_foo = foo 

function the_other_object:some_func()
  -- does some stuff
  reference_to_foo:bar( true )
end
```

Calling the foo:bar() works well, but per reference_to_foo the index self becomes the argument (boolean in this case).

In :bar(), I'll get this error:

> attempt to index local 'self' (a boolean value)

Why is that and how can I solve this?

Comment: Have you made sure to use reference_to_foo:bar (with a colon), as you did in your sample code? How did you define the_other_object and how exactly do you call :some_func? It would be good if you provided a fully functional (or in this case, unfunctional) sample that includes nothing more than the code that you need to reproduce the problem.